# Change color of selection

Tags: html, css

When you select text in browser, most often background behind text being selected changes color to blue. How to change this color to another?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for the `selection` pseudo-element.

```
::-moz-selection{ background: #000; color:#fff;}
::selection { background:#000; color:#fff; }
```

Also, as a side note. If you plan on using text-shadow in your site at all, I would recommend adding `text-shadow:none;` to your `::selection` styling. As you can see in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bCtQQ/18/) fiddle, it is really hard on the eyes.

Comment: Makes it easier to say if you use the correct name "pseudo-element".

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, but so much less fun XD. Still, I'll make sure to change it to the correct wording.

Comment: Just FYI I wouldn't worry about anything besides IE8, anything below IE8 is pretty much extinct.

Comment: I'm actually surprised and pleased that Microsoft bothered to add support for `::selection` in IE9, even though it's gone from the CSS3 spec.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at this article...

http://css-tricks.com/490-overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/

... so something like this:

```
p.moz::-moz-selection {
    background:#cc0000;
    color:#fff;
}

p.webkit::-webkit-selection {
    background:#cc0000;
    color:#fff;
}

p.normal::selection {
    background:#cc0000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Comment: Because CSS cascades,  you should always make sure to put vendor prefixed selectors above their "standardized" selector. Otherwise, future browsers would still default to their own vendor-implementation, even if they added support for the standardized version.

Comment: @Moses... I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Vendor prefixes exist as a means for browsers to implement features before those features have been officially standardized by W3C. However, once an official standard exists there is no reason for future browsers to require prefixes. Using your code the browser would first encounter the standardized `::selection`, then later in the stylesheet it sees `::-moz-selection`. Because the browser now understands both, it will choose the second one because it encountered it last. This is bad because you most likely want to use the new and standardized implementation, not the old version.

Comment: @Moses... ahhh. gotcha. so the regular `::selection` should be last as the default standard styling?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
::selection
{
background:#999;
color:#fff;
}
```