# Changing text selection colour

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change color of selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931129/change-color-of-selection)

How does [this site](http://popwatch.ew.com/2011/09/10/torchwood-season-finale-death/) manage to make text selection pink, rather than my browser default of blue?

[image]

Comment: @David: [That is not a typo.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/colour)

Comment: Thanks for making me aware that Torchwood has a fourth season - it was never really close to my heart, but decent entertainment nevertheless.

Comment: That exact *colour* of selection usually means the site is using http://html5boilerplate.com/.

Comment: @thirtydot: Ah, interesting! They're not, but it's interesting. (In fact the selection colours are slightly different, and the rest of the relevant stylesheet doesn't match either.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be defined through the `::selection` pseudo-element:

```
::selection {
background: #FF5E99;
color: white;
text-shadow: none;
}
```

See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html

- IE9 supports it, prior IE's don't
- Firefox supports it through `::-moz-selection`
- Chrome and Safari seem to support it fully.

Answer (score 2):

use `::selection` and `::-moz-selection`  selector to style your selection.

```
::selection{background:black; color:white}
::-moz-selection{background:black; color:white}
```

You need two separate rules for moz and standard. 
Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3A%3Aselection

Note that there is no `::-webkit-selection` rule

Comment: It has to be written with two (redundant) rules: `::selection { ... } ::-moz-selection { ... }`. The selector `::selection, ::-moz-selection` doesn't work (for some reason).

Comment: @Šime: "Redundant" [loosely] means not required, but your comment is all about them being required. Which is it?!

Comment: @Tomalak I used the wrong term. Not redundant, but there have to be two separate rules. For instance: `::selection { background-color:yellow; } ::-moz-selection { background-color:yellow; }`. If the `::selection, ::-moz-selection` selector is used, Firefox ignores the whole rule...

Answer (score 1):

In [one](http://img2-short.timeinc.net/ew/static/c/common_min.css?ver=2) of the CSS files of the page whose link you gave,
found this:

```
::-moz-selection{background:#ff5e99;color:#fff;text-shadow:none}
```

Hope that's self explanatory.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was searching for.