# What property defines the color of text select in css?

Tags: css

I am actually do not even know hot to define this, but I need to change the text background color. Never did this. Now when I am selecting the text, lets say pressing the left mouse button and marking a proportion of the text all the background becomes red, so I do not know what element defines this property.

Comment: I don't think this is set by css, I believe its a browser / OS feature

Comment: @simonmorley Nop - it can be set by css - just not all browsers support it.

Comment: I just learned something new :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change color of selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931129/change-color-of-selection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for this (note double : is correct):

```
::selection {color:#fff;background:red;}
::-moz-selection {color:#fff;background:red;}
```

Comment: There is no `::-webkit-selection`.

Comment: @BoltClock - not exactly - there is - just no browser implemented it. Which kinda makes it useless. -_-

Comment: That doesn't make sense. What do you mean by "there is"?

Comment: Uh, I will have to correct myself here - ::-webkit-selection is not part of webkit - also ::selection was dropped out from official CSS3 spec - but modern browsers still support it. Fixed - thanks for noting.

Answer (score 2):

You need the `::selection` pseudo-element:

```
::selection {
    background-color: red;
}
```

However, note that since this is a fairly new CSS3 selector, you need to use the browser specific prefixes for maximum compatibility:

```
::-moz-selection
```

Also be aware that this has been [removed from the CSS3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selection). It will not work in IE below version 9, but will work in the majority of other modern browsers.