# How to change colour of blue highlight on select box dropdown

Tags: css

How do I change the blue highlight on this dropdown please?

[link to select box demo](http://www.playground.jonathanlyon.com/ark/dropdown.html)

I'd like to change the highlight color to gray if this is possible.

```css
select {
  border: 0;
  color: #EEE;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  width: 378px;
  *width: 350px;
  *background: #58B14C;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#mainselection {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 350px;
  -moz-border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
  border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 11px #330033;
  background: url("http://www.danielneumann.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/arrow.gif") no-repeat scroll 319px 5px #58B14C;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainselection">
  <select>
    <option>Select an Option</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667086/changing-select-highlight-color/1667105

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Select List Option background colour on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)

Comment: I don't think you can. You can set background of individual options, but not the highlight. You may want to consider jQuery plugins e.g. http://dev7studios.com/dropit/

Comment: Please refer to this [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931129/change-color-of-selection

Comment: Suresh's suggestion does not work.

Answer (score 27):

Yes, you could change the background of `select` but you will not be able to change the highlight color (when you hover) by using CSS!

> You have few options:

1. Is to convert `select` into `ul, li` kind of select and do anything you want with this.
2. Use libraries like [Choosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) or [jQuery Form Styler](https://github.com/Dimox/jQueryFormStyler) . These allow you to style in much more broad and cross-browser way.

Comment: Select2 is pretty decent, using the OS UX but not overdoing it with crazy styled selectors that people just don't know how to use.. but no +1 cause its not really answering the question OP asked...

Comment: @ppumkin What do you want to say, pal, I'm not sure??

Comment: Is this still true?

Answer (score 13):

I believe you are looking for the `outline` CSS property (in conjunction with active and hover psuedo attributes):

```
/* turn it off completely */
select:active, select:hover {
  outline: none
}

/* make it red instead (with with same width and style) */
select:active, select:hover {
  outline-color: red
}
```

Full details of outline, outline-color, outline-style, and outline-width
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline

Comment: I think this is the background highlight and not the focus outline

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all - the OP wants to replace the browser's default blue highlight with another color.

Answer (score 11):

Just found this whilst looking for a solution. I've only tested it FF 32.0.3

```
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #fff inset;
```

Comment: `select option:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #e1358f inset;
}` works, but only in FF and only when your mouse stays on the element, it turns blue the moment you move away from the select box while it is still open.

Comment: @CPHPython Perhaps can use something like [select2](https://select2.org/)

Comment: @Anima-t3d thanks, I am familiar with select2, but I was just trying to limit the usage of the number of plugins.

Comment: Styling native select element is very tricky, I think using a plugin for this is one of the most common use cases.

Answer (score 9):

try this.. I know it's an old post but it might help somebody

```
select option:hover,
    select option:focus,
    select option:active {
        background: linear-gradient(#000000, #000000);
        background-color: #000000 !important; /* for IE */
        color: #ffed00 !important;
    }

    select option:checked {
        background: linear-gradient(#d6d6d6, #d6d6d6);
        background-color: #d6d6d6 !important; /* for IE */
        color: #000000 !important;
    }
```

Comment: It styles only background of checked option, doesn't work on hover. But anyway it is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

When we click on an "input" element, it gets "focused" on. Removing the blue highlighter for this "focus" action is as simple as below. To give it gray color, you could define a gray border.

```
select:focus{
    border-color: gray;
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it changes the border color when the select is focused. However, the box shadow should be overritten as well: 'box-shadow: 0 0 2px gray;' to remove the blue color entirely.

Comment: yeah, i am also listening this radio of issue

Comment: Does not work for hovering over an option, instead this turns the entire background of the dropdown to this background color.  The Question asked was how do we change the default blue highlight color.

Answer (score 2):

This works for firefox and chrome, falls back gracefully to the system color in IE. Just be sure to set the title property to the content of the option. It allows you to set the background and foreground colors.

```
select option:checked:after {
    content: attr(title);
    background: #666;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: This is super hacky but it does exactly what I wanted. Thank you :) (Works with Electron, too, FYI)

Comment: Not working in chrome 63 or firefox 57... And pseudo-elements use two colons?

Answer (score 2):

To both style the hover color and avoid the OS default color in Firefox, you need to add a box-shadow to both the select option *and* select option:hover declarations, setting the color of the box-shadow on "select option" to the menu background color.

```
select option {
  background: #f00; 
  color: #fff; 
  box-shadow: inset 20px 20px #f00
} 

select option:hover {
  color: #000; 
  box-shadow: inset 20px 20px #00f;
}
```

Comment: This does NOT get rid of the blue hover colour you get when moving the cursor over the dropdown options.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. Although as @klokop mentioned, it does not get rid of the blue hover.

Answer (score -3):

i just found this site that give a cool themes for the select box
http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/

and you can try this themes if your problem with the overall look 
[blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeGbH.png) - [yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsvnS.png) - [grey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxq4Q.png)

Answer (score -4):

Add this in your CSS code and change the red background-color with a color of your choice:

```
.dropdown-menu>.active>a {color:black; background-color:red;}
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus {color:black; background-color:red;}
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover {color:black; background-color:red;}
```