# Selected value in select with color

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select list which has options with colors (green good option, red bad option etc..). When i click on my select list i see that my options are in colors which i have defined, but when i selected that value i would like that selected value has his own color, not white by default or blue when changing thru options. Below is my code snippet.

```html
<select id="myBox">
  <option style="color:red">
    red
  </option>
  <option style="color:blue">
    blue
  </option>
  <option style="color:green">
    green
  </option>
</select>
```

Is it possible customize that "default" (blue and white) colors and how?

Comment: Another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388011/how-to-change-colour-of-blue-highlight-on-select-box-dropdown

Comment: It is similar, but only about blue highlight. I would like here also that my selected value takes the color of the selected option.

Comment: Have you tried using `background-color`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it without jQuery. Pass a function to the `onchange` attribute of your select, and add a `color` attribute to each element. Then in the function you pass to `onchange`, get the selected item, get it's `color` attribute, then change the `outline` and `color` properties of your select's `style`.

```js
function selectChanged() {
  var select = document.getElementById("myBox");
  var item = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
  var color = item.getAttribute("color");
  if (color === 'none') {
    select.style.color = "black";
    select.style.outline = "none";
  } else {
    select.style.outline = "solid " + color + " 1px";
    select.style.color = color;
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="myBox" onchange="selectChanged()">
  <option color="none" style="color: black">
    --
  </option>
  <option color="red" style="color:red">
    red
  </option>
  <option color="blue" style="color:blue">
    blue
  </option>
  <option color="green" style="color:green">
    green
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `change` event function on the select and then set its style attribute as the style of the selected option.

```
<script>
$().ready(function(){
    $("#myBox").on("change",function()
    {
      var style = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("style");  
      $(this).attr("style",style);  
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/woj7mers/3/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Sure. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

@KuKeC You can use jquery for this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#myBox').change(function(){
            var selectedColor = $('#myBox option:selected').text()
          console.log(selectedColor)
          $('#myBox ').css({'background': selectedColor, 'color' : '#FFFFFF' })
      })
    })
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.
NOTE: I have added an id to your select box.

Here an example for you and eventually following users:

https://jsfiddle.net/8ge7eomr/

If this was usefull for you I will apreciate if you will up vote it.

If you need some more changes for it, just let me know.

Comment: Woops! Something is going wrong I will update the fiddle and re-post it

Comment: @KuKeC I have updated the answer with working (I hope) the fiddle link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me a lot.