# HTML hide select tag inside button tag

Tags: html

I want the select options to show up when you press a button but not have the bar showing the selected option to appear inside the button.

This is what i have so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button>
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</button>
  
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I want it to look like, then I will place an image inside the button

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button>
<select style="display: none;">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</button>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, that simply doesn't look like valid HTML.

Comment: @BramVanroy it is valid HTML, however I don't understand the logic of having the `select` field...inside of a button...

Comment: it runs, and it just a snippet to demonstrate what I want

Comment: @m_callens the idea is to run it on mobile, so I can have the options pop up and then selected from a smaller button that fits in to the design of the applicaiotn

Comment: @m_callens If you run it through a validator, you'll see that it is not valid.

Comment: @BramVanroy it runs I am not to worried about the validity of it, until after I know there is a way to do what I want

Comment: @BramVanroy ok fair enough, the invalid parts I saw where the missing `<head></head>` and that `select` cannot be a descendant of `button`

Comment: @m_callens if select can not descend from button is there away to replace what the standard select appearance is to an image?

Comment: @JacobLawton If you want to change the appearance of core HTML components, learn CSS and/or use a framework like `bootstrap` or `semantic-ui`

Comment: @m_callens so your saying that I can not hide the select display?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change colour of blue highlight on select box dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388011/how-to-change-colour-of-blue-highlight-on-select-box-dropdown)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#btn, .close").click(function() {
  $(".select-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.select-wrapper {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.select-wrapper select {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.select-wrapper.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/120/60/" id="btn">
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <input type="button" value="close" class="close">
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to use a button with an image on it, and the selected option is still displayed which will ruin the layout I have

Comment: What do you mean with "the selected option is displayed"? How else would a user know what they have selected?

Comment: I will give it an ID then get the value in javascript from the id, the displaying part is not important. I have tried the "style = display: none" but that makes it so the options do not show up either

Comment: It is not at all clear what you want. Provide an image of what you want if possible.

Comment: I have edited the question it has an example of what I would want

Comment: It doesn't. What *behaviour* do you expect? What do you need to happen when someone clicks the button?

Comment: It to show the select options, if you run this on a mobile browser, it brings up the options as a pop out, that is what I want to happen I just don't want the box with ("Volvo" ect) to be displayed inside the button

Comment: So you want that when someone clicks the button, the select becomes visible, like, below the button?

Comment: just the options, so if you look at select on a mobile device it opens as a pop out (like an alert box), I want it to do that. I am not worried about its desktop functionailty

Comment: See my edit. This should give you enough information to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem that the dev refused to just use list due to some backend issue.

found a simple cheat to make the select tag show all the options, that look like a dropdown, and then I just toggle the whole select tag. Not exactly what you asking for, but looks like it.

```js
$("#btn, .selector").click(function() {
  $(".select-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.select-wrapper{
  display: none;
  }
  
  
.select-wrapper.active {
  display: block;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

add variable:
<br>
<input type="button" value="add" id="btn">
<div class="select-wrapper">
<select size="4" class="selector">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
</div>





</body>
```