# How to remove default border radius from IE11/Edge on Select tag

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

So,

I have styled a select tag, and when I view it on IE11/Edge it adds a black border around the select box when you click the dropdown arrow.

I cannot seem to find anything that will remove this border.

Please advise.

here is my CSS

```
select {
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 59.6px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;   
    padding-left: 17px;
    background: url('##Pathtoimg##') no-repeat 96% #ffffff;
    outline: 0;
    border-color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a `:focus` property. Try adding `select:focus {border:0;}`

Comment: There are apparently no direct css to control it. but this is the only thing I can recommend to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388011/how-to-change-colour-of-blue-highlight-on-select-box-dropdown

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix anything, please see the screenshot of the problem. http://i.imgur.com/aqFZKnx.png

Comment: can u send me demo link plz?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot send a demo link, but the screenshot should be enough, and the CSS too.

Comment: @Logeshwaran I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/p0pkuequ/)...

Comment: @BarryHanbury Please edit your question and use a code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in IE because  element style will vary depending on Browsers. IE use one style where Safari use another style.

We'll take a sample for our example:

```
<select id="something" name="something">
  <option value="1">This is option 1</option>
  <option value="2">This is option 2</option>
  <option value="3">This is option 3</option>
  <option value="4">This is option 4</option>
  <option value="5">This is option 5</option>
</select>
```

Check(run) this in all different browsers. All browsers style for `<select>` element will vary.