# How can I remove focus from select box Options using javascript and css

Tags: javascript, css

I want to remove focus outline from select options but not from select. how can i do that? I did the following for the select box

```
select:focus{
  outline:0px
}
```

I want to do the same for options.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/Javascript_Form_How_to/Select/Remove_focus_from_the_select_box.htm

Answer (score 0):

When a child `<option>` of the parent `<select>` menu is selected/focused it will populate the `<select>` with the selection and show a focus ring around the element for this reason.

`<select>` is the parent element of all of your `<option>` child elements.

The way your `<select>` menu also displays is also dictated by a few things including your current OS/browser:

**e.g.:** *all `<option>` elements display with a blue background on `:hover` and `:focus` on a Mac for instance*

So you have the option of either removing a focus outline entirely from the `<select>` element and its children OR changing your `<select>` element into a `<ul>` with `<li>` elements that can be styled at will.

Please see this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388011/how-to-change-colour-of-blue-highlight-on-select-box-dropdown) for more detail.

--

**Please Note**: The focus outline serves the purpose of making your element accessible for users on screen readers, so if you remove any sort of focus behavior for selected elements - folks using keyboard navigation won't be able to tell which item is selected. You can check out the [W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G195.html#G195-examples) for best practices.

You could implement two different types of `<select>` behavior for users with accessibility concerns (e.g.: adding a class to elements in the event that a screen reader is detected - which can be challenging, so check out this great [Hackernoon blog post](https://hackernoon.com/removing-that-ugly-focus-ring-and-keeping-it-too-6c8727fefcd2) on the matter) to make sure both types of users' needs are taken care of.

--