# How to change the hover colour in drop downlist of select box in jsp

Tags: jquery, css

How to change the hover colour in  drop downlist of select box in jsp
The default colour is blue how to make as user prefered colour ?

[image: Image Reference]

Comment: show your code please

Comment: add some example or visual aid which explain what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: <select name="numbers" id="number_id">

 <option value="" disabled>ONE</option>
    <option value="2">TWO</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
 
</select>

Comment: its a simple html select tag ,just want to change the hover  colour in drop downlist  to other right now its blue

Comment: Image added  click the image reference link  @Sanira

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change colour of blue highlight on select box dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388011/how-to-change-colour-of-blue-highlight-on-select-box-dropdown)

Comment: Sorry those links never help me

Comment: @ jiju--BaD DeVeLoPer do you want it to be `select` tage? you can not achieve what you've trying to do with CSS. but you can achieve the same effects by using `ul` `li` tags.

Answer (score 0):

The blue color, is the default color rendered by browser.

You can add/ implement the plugin like [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)