# CSS - unable to remove default hover style from option element (the child of select)

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to style `option` element, add my own `hover` color instead of the default blue. I am able to change the background color, but not the hover effect. How can I change it?
[My code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mQmxjN)

CSS:

```
select option {
  background-color:red;
}
select option:hover {
color:black;
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <select>
         <option> 18 per page</option>
         <option> 10 per page</option>
         <option> 5 per page</option>
       </select>
</div>
```

Comment: it's working fine, but the selection color is above it (add hover using dev tools to see it)

Comment: Please follow the below link it might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388011/how-to-change-colour-of-blue-highlight-on-select-box-dropdown