# Removing hover effect from select drop down menu in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI for my react project and using the select dropdown that has been shown in the Material UI documentation. On clicking the second set of select drop down (native Select) options appears with a default blue hover effect. How can I disable the hover effect from the select element drop down menu using custom theme?

```
import React from 'react';[![enter image description here][1]][1]
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import OutlinedInput from '@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';


const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    minWidth: 120,
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
  },
});

class NativeSelects extends React.Component {
  state = {
    age: '',
    labelWidth: 0,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      labelWidth: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.InputLabelRef).offsetWidth,
    });
  }

  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="age-native-simple">Age</InputLabel>
          <Select
            native
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange('age')}
            inputProps={{
              name: 'age',
              id: 'age-native-simple',
            }}
          >
            <option value="" />
            <option value={10}>Ten</option>
            <option value={20}>Twenty</option>
            <option value={30}>Thirty</option>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>

        <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel
            ref={ref => {
              this.InputLabelRef = ref;
            }}
            htmlFor="outlined-age-native-simple"
          >
            Age
          </InputLabel>
          <Select
            native
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange('age')}
            input={
              <OutlinedInput
                name="age"
                labelWidth={this.state.labelWidth}
                id="outlined-age-native-simple"
              />
            }
          >
            <option value="" />
            <option value={10}>Ten</option>
            <option value={20}>Twenty</option>
            <option value={30}>Thirty</option>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

NativeSelects.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(NativeSelects);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change colour of blue highlight on select box dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388011/how-to-change-colour-of-blue-highlight-on-select-box-dropdown)

Comment: For the native select, this is not controlled by Material-UI and is different in different browsers.