# How to remove blue background for focus/hover on select/option dropdown

Tags: html, css

How do i remove the blue background when active on an option and hovering on an option with my select dropdown.

Here is a screenshot of what i mean:

[image]

I have tried every css rule i could thin off and even search the internet, including here but nothing is working

```css
.language {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -45px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.language select {
  width: 180px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: '';
  cursor: pointer;
}

.language select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.language option {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.language option:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.language-selector::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f0ac";
  visibility: visible;
  font-weight: 900;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1690px;
  margin-top: -53px;
}
```

```html
<div class="language">
  <select>
    <option value="">English</option>
    <option value="">Deutsch</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You may be able to try a few fixes from this thread here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388011/how-to-change-colour-of-blue-highlight-on-select-box-dropdown

Comment: To customize a select box, you have design a select box that works exactly like the order dropdown and then sync them together, and overlap the former with the later.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't. This is set by the OS. Sorry :/

Comment: This should be a comment. This is not an answer. Even if it is by OS, still dropdowns and select boxes can be customized.

Comment: Well, I disagree and I am sorry you feel this way; it IS an answer and a good one if you ask me. Straight in the point. The question is about options and not select boxes. Providing alternative solutions like dropdowns is out of the scope of the question.

Comment: @Code_Ninja So show a working example. None of the dupes work in several browsers without creating a real widget

Comment: @mplungjan would it be okay, if I share an external link where I have customized the dropdown, since I feel too lazy to gather the code from there?

Comment: @mplungjan let me find the link.

Comment: @mplungjan [Here](https://cn.fresh.com/cn/lotusmaskapply) is a link to a page where dropdowns are customized. Its in Chineses though. Please check.

Comment: @mplungjan The CSS in this link might not as good as it should be, its made by a newbie, but it will provide a vague idea.

Comment: @Code_Ninja I see a blue background https://imgur.com/a/DVHI89O in Chrome.. Works in Edge

Comment: @scooterlord - so actually some browser DO allow it. See code_ninja's link in Edge

Comment: Hacks and shivs will always be there or random browser-specific styling. But, what's the point if not used by all major browsers? Edge is considered obsolete and its support is already dropped, so I don't see any victories here. Also, in the link mentioned, the left one is NOT a select element, and the right select element shows exactly like how it should in Edge - that is default select style.

Comment: Yes this is a hack, but if you target at presenting the data to customers or people who visit your website, it works as it gives you a custom select box.

Comment: The OP explicitly  states 'select dropdown', the image attached is indeed a select dropdown. Providing solutions not focused on styling the select element is out of scope of the initial question.

Comment: But when we are trying to provide a solution during development, the only aim that we have is not element/task oriented, but it is also to figure out whether there a way around or not. So this is a way around.

Comment: To give an end to the argument: the link that was provided in the comments shows a 'custom dropdown element'-aka NOT a select dropdown, and a select dropdown that is semi-styled without providing a solution to the actual question about the options select. I have done extensive research when writing my own framework and you can't avoid this. There are specific reasons why people want default select elements styled than using plugins or any other 'custom select' (eg native behavior on mobile devices). Also one cannot guess, estimate or assume what the OP wants/needs which is exactly what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
:focus {outline:0 !important;}
```

and this

```
:hover {outline:0 !important;}
```

If this is not working try on ur own css style !importent this will overwrite all the normall css

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd use `background: transparent` but you have to tell us the rule that's setting the blue color or if it's the OS/browser as someone else mentioned, tell us which OS/browser. Dropdown attributes can't always be styled as many are set by the browser (see the diff between them in Firefox and Chrome). The solution for complete style control is unfortunately to create your own dropdowns using a trigger and list of items you toggle visibility and handle the user's selection.

Answer (score 0):

hi It's happend for me and this is mt solution {background: transparent !important;}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.