# How to change the highlight colour of the selected element in a drop down menu suing css?

Tags: css, select, colors, element, selected

Hej,
I made a standard drop down menu in my Laravel project, like this:

```
<select class="product_select" name="products" id="products">
                <option value="pilsner">Pilsner</option>
                <option value="wheat">Wheat</option>
                <option value="ipa">IPA</option>
                <option value="stout">Stout</option>
                <option value="ale">Ale</option>
                <option value="alcohol-free">Alcohol Free</option>
            </select>
```

However, the standard colour for highlighting the selected element is blue.
How can I change it to gray? Does anyone know, how can I do it with css or with JavaScript?
[The selected element is highlighted with blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8xfN.png)

Comment: This was extremely easy to find via search. Does this answer your question? [How to change colour of blue highlight on select box dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388011/how-to-change-colour-of-blue-highlight-on-select-box-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `option:hover` for that. Here is an example that makes the background-color gray.

```
option:hover { 
   background-color : gray;
}
```