# Can we change blue color for the hover on drop down html select element

Tags: html, css

I need to change the blue color to red for
mouse hover on HTML select dropdown component:

see the image [image]

```
<select>
        <option>Apple</option>
        <option>Orange</option>
        <option>Berry</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thats done by the browser. you'll have to use a custom component. most css solutions won't universally work.

Comment: If that's important to you, you can use alternates to `<seelct>` like select2 https://select2.org/appearance or bootstrap dropdown menus - both of those allow you to style the appearance

Comment: I will try select2

Comment: I used select2 , it is a very good  solution also it is clone all events listeners

Comment: Welcome to the comunity. Please notice this question has already been answered here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388011/how-to-change-colour-of-blue-highlight-on-select-box-dropdown