# convert multiple class name to one class in html

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

i am using tailwind pre defined css in my vue project .

```
<p class="bg-white text-black focus:text-red focus:bg-white-2 dark:text-white dark:bg-black dark:focus:bg-black-2 dark:focus:text-yellow">some text</p>
<p class="bg-white text-black focus:text-red focus:bg-white-2 dark:text-white dark:bg-black dark:focus:bg-black-2 dark:focus:text-yellow">some text2</p>
<p class="bg-white text-black focus:text-red focus:bg-white-2 dark:text-white dark:bg-black dark:focus:bg-black-2 dark:focus:text-yellow">some text 3</p>
<p class="bg-white text-black focus:text-red focus:bg-white-2 dark:text-white dark:bg-black dark:focus:bg-black-2 dark:focus:text-yellow">some other text</p>
<p class="bg-white text-black focus:text-red focus:bg-white-2 dark:text-white dark:bg-black dark:focus:bg-black-2 dark:focus:text-yellow">more texttttttttt</p>
```

as you can see for each tag i have to type all this multiple classes.
what i want is that is there any way to make variable class to work on class like this

```
<p class="grouped-class">text</p>
<p class="grouped-class">text 2</p>
<p class="grouped-class">text 3</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use @apply

HTML:

```
 <!-- Before extracting a custom class -->
<button class="py-2 px-4 bg-blue-500 text-white font-semibold rounded-lg shadow-md hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-400 focus:ring-opacity-75">
  Save changes
</button>

<!-- After extracting a custom class -->
<button class="btn-primary">
  Save changes
</button>
```

CSS:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .btn-primary {
    @apply py-2 px-4 bg-blue-500 text-white font-semibold rounded-lg shadow-md hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-400 focus:ring-opacity-75;
  }
}
```

From the tailwind docs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#layer

Comment: thanks-@Marshal :- one more doubt how can we change default blue color of <select> or <input type="date > while choosing. i mean is there any tailwind css class to do that

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388011/how-to-change-colour-of-blue-highlight-on-select-box-dropdown